# is it possible to use apache mahout classification without hadoop dependency

Tags: java, windows, hadoop, windows-7, classification

Is it possible to use Apache mahout classification without any dependency to Hadoop.
I would like to use the mahout algorithm on a single computer by only including the mahout library inside my Java project but i dont want to use hadoop at all since i will be running on a single node anyway, windows 7 operating system.

Is that possible?
If yes , which algorithm run without hadoop dependency?

Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to run Mahout without having to install a Hadoop cluster. All you need to do is set the environment variable

```
MAHOUT_LOCAL=TRUE
```

On seeing this variable, Mahout will start interacting directly with the file system for data, etc. without trying to look for a Hadoop cluster or a HDFS location.

Comment: I tried but it does not have any effect  " hadoop binary is not in PATH,HADOOP_HOME/bin,HADOOP_PREFIX/bin, running locally "

Comment: Isn't that what you are looking for? Run Mahout locally, instead of on a Hadoop cluster?